# Why jQuery selector works on Chrome but not on Safari?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, safari

I have the following code:

```js
var l = $("input[name*=hello").length;
$('#result').text(l);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input name="hello" type="text">
</div>
<div>
  <input name="hello" type="text">
</div>
<div id="result">
  
</div>
```

Where the jQuery selector is:

```
input[name*=hello
```

Check that the selector is not correctly written `input[name*=hello` since a `]` is missing.

On Chrome I get on the div[id=result] the amount of inputs that I have with the name "hello" (2).

But on Safari I get an error on the Console:

[image]

Which is correct, so the question is: Why did Chrome "autocorrect" the selector? Is it possible to remove that behaviour?

Comment: This also works on Firefox, even with `document.querySelectorAll`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode

Comment: Perhaps, in their later version, they are much sophisticated that they fix selector by themselves. Same as almost all browsers today fix broken html: `<div> <h1> </div>` is fixed.

Comment: 'use strict'; has no impact on the result.

Answer (score 0):

If the selector doesn't contain any jQuery extensions, jQuery will use the browser's built-in `document.querySelectorAll()` function. When the selector is invalid, the behavior is unspecified, so it may differ between browsers. Some browsers try to "fix" the selector and return something useful, while other browsers signal an error. You shouldn't depend on this -- write correct selectors.